# How to use tf.nn.fused_batch_norm

Tags: tensorflow

I need some simple examples through which I can learn how to use `tf.nn.fused_batch_norm`. (I couldn find none through google search.)

Specifically, I want to precisely understand the input parts `mean=None, variance=None` in the function. In **inference stage**, do I calculate the population mean and variance by, say, tf.nn.moments, and then put them into the function with these input arguments?

And do I use this function just like any other activations like ReLU and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the definition file of [tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py)

```
def _fused_batch_norm(self, inputs, training):
    """Returns the output of fused batch norm."""

    def _fused_batch_norm_training():
        return nn.fused_batch_norm(
            inputs,
            self.gamma,
            self.beta,
            epsilon=self.epsilon)

    def _fused_batch_norm_inference():
        return nn.fused_batch_norm(
            inputs,
            self.gamma,
            self.beta,
            mean=self.moving_mean,
            variance=self.moving_variance,
            epsilon=self.epsilon,
            is_training=False)

    output, mean, variance = tf_utils.smart_cond(
        training, _fused_batch_norm_training, _fused_batch_norm_inference)
    if not self._bessels_correction_test_only:
        # Remove Bessel's correction to be consistent with non-fused batch norm.
        # Note that the variance computed by fused batch norm is
        # with Bessel's correction.
        sample_size = math_ops.cast(
                array_ops.size(inputs) / array_ops.size(variance), variance.dtype)
        factor = (sample_size - math_ops.cast(1.0, variance.dtype)) / sample_size
        variance *= factor

    training_value = tf_utils.constant_value(training)
    if training_value is None:
        momentum = tf_utils.smart_cond(training,
                                       lambda: self.momentum,
                                       lambda: 1.0)
    else:
        momentum = ops.convert_to_tensor(self.momentum)
    if training_value or training_value is None:
        mean_update = self._assign_moving_average(self.moving_mean, mean,
                                                  momentum)
        variance_update = self._assign_moving_average(self.moving_variance,
                                                      variance, momentum)
        self.add_update(mean_update, inputs=True)
        self.add_update(variance_update, inputs=True)

    return output
```